# Proof of $\text{#Hom}_K (L,K) \leq [L:K]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $L/K$ be finite extension, then how can I prove this?
$$\text{#}\text{Hom}_K (L,K) \leq [L:K]$$

What I know is I can represent $L$ as $K(a_1, a_2,...,a_n)$ but I can't go any further. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You work one simple extension at a time.

On simple extension $Hom_K(L,K^a) \leqslant [L:K]$ as the left number counts the different roots of the minimal polynomial and the right number equals the degree of the minimal polynomial.

Hence the inequality follows by grace of the two tower formulas for separability
degree and degree.

Comment: what is $\#Hom_k(L,K)$?

Comment: Number of $K$-embeddings. Which is the number of roots of the minimal polynomial

Comment: This is the definition I use: Let $L/K$ and $M/K$ be field extensions, a $K$-embedding  of $L$ into $M$ is an (injecitive) field homomorphism  $\sigma: L\rightarrow M$ such that $\sigma\vert_K = id_K$.

Comment: but wouldn't $Hom_K(L,K)$ consist of functions from $L$ to $K$?

Comment: sorry I meant $Hom_K(L,K^a)$ from $L$ to the algebraic closure